# c# odbc max field length problem

Tags: c#, odbc

```
OdbcConnection cnn = new OdbcConnection(config.connectstrings.odbcmain(_table)); OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cnn);

cnn.Open();

OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

dr.Read();

//this is 240 chars:

Console.WriteLine(dr[0]);

cnn.Close();
```

Has anyone else run into this with the dotnet framework odbc provider? The field is 240 chars -- I can read it correctly using other ways, so the data is ok

what happens is when using this c# code is it read ~the first 200 characters, then it injects the beginning chars into the last 40 (overwriting the last 40)--

this sample code is as simple as I could go to try & find the problem--

connection string:

DRIVER={ODBC Driver};

Comment: Could you post the connection string (without any user names / passwords, of course). My preliminary research shows other people have had this problem, too. Also, what type of database are you connecting to via ODBC? Is ODBC the only option you have available for accessing the database?

Comment: yes, odbc is the only way -- isam files